# Is there any away to trigger GitHub action workflow from Shiny Dashboard?

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I'm looking for a way to trigger GitHub action workflow from the dashboard by simply clicking on a button. Also, is there any way to embed live logs of GitHub workflows on shiny dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `respository_dispatch` event to trigger the workflow. Once the action is configured you can create a dispatch event by doing a POST request to GitHub API dispatches endpoint.

`POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/dispatches`

Refer [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/event-payloads/#repository_dispatch) for more info.